# Eclipse plugin development: Disabling Java Structure Compare when comparing files?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I used the following code to compare two files:

```
CompareConfiguration config = new CompareConfiguration();
config.setRightEditable(false);
config.setLeftEditable(false);
config.setLeftLabel("Klasse 1");
config.setRightLabel("Klasse 2");
config.setProperty(CompareConfiguration.USE_OUTLINE_VIEW, Boolean.FALSE);

CompareUI.openCompareEditorOnPage(new EditorInput(config, file1, file2), page);
```

This works and a compare editor is opened. But unfortunately, the Java Source Compare and the Java Structure Compare is openend. I want to permanently disable Java Structure Compare. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a CompareEditorInput (instead of EditorInput) and then setting the Configuration property of that to a CompareConfiguration which you can set the set a preference store using one of it's constructors. The ComparePreferences has a preference of doing the structure compare (or not presumably).

Comment: I use a CompareConfiguration, but I don't know which property to set.

Comment: Look at ComparePreferencePage, there is an OPEN_STRUCTURE_COMPARE property

Comment: I added this line but nothing changed: config.setProperty(ComparePreferencePage.OPEN_STRUCTURE_COMPARE, false);

Comment: Yes it works now. But i get a discouraged access but that shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException do you remember how you got this to work? I'm working on something similar now

Comment: For posterity, I got it working with this line:
`CompareUIPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().setValue(ComparePreferencePage.OPEN_STRUCTURE_COMPARE, Boolean.FALSE);`

Answer (score 12):

Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Compare/Patch

un-check 'Open structure compare automatically'.

Apply and Close.

[image: Ref]